# handled SQL exception being flagged as unhandled

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Ok here is my code fragment:

```
     try 
    {

        res = gfSQL.doSQL("SELECT TIMESTAMP, MSGLEVEL, APPLICATION, STREAM, THREADID, " +
                          " THREADNAME, REQUESTID, MESSAGE, ID, PROCESSED" +
                           " FROM GFLOG where PROCESSED = 'N'" +
                           " ORDER BY TIMESTAMP, ID");
    } catch ( SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(128);
    }

    if (! res.first()) {  <<<---- FLAGGED STATEMENT
        // no data to process  
        System.err.println("No data found to process\n");
        return;
    }
```

Now java is flagging the indicating statement (and just about everyone after it) with a 'Unhandled exception type SQLException).  gfSQL.doSQL throws this exception and is defined with:

public ResultSet doSQL(String sqlCommand) throws SQLException
    {

The funny thing is - if I repeat the 'catch' block like so:

```
try 
    {

        res = gfSQL.doSQL("SELECT TIMESTAMP, MSGLEVEL, APPLICATION, STREAM, THREADID, " +
                          " THREADNAME, REQUESTID, MESSAGE, ID, PROCESSED" +
                           " FROM GFLOG where PROCESSED = 'N'" +
                           " ORDER BY TIMESTAMP, ID");
    } catch ( SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(128);
    } catch ( SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(128);
    }
    if (! res.first()) {
        // no data to process
```

No 'unhandled' error is flagged.  (however the duplicate catch phrase is flagged as an 'unreachable catch block - SQLException is already handled' of course.)

Any ideas why Java sees the catch in one instance but not the other?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `gfSQL.doSQL()`can throw a SQLException, and you're catching it.

But `res.first()`can also throw a SQLException, and you're not catching it, since this instruction is out of the try block. That's why you get the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

`res.first()` should be in the try block as it can throw an exception:

```
try {
    res = // ...
    if(!res.first()) {
        // ...
    }
} catch ( SQLException e) {
    // ...
}
```